# Black Screen in any camera app

Tags: virtualbox, hp, webcam

I have installed oracle virtual box extension also to make USB 2.0 to work.
The host is windows 10
I have freshly installed ubuntu, on which I want to turn on the webcam.

I turned on the USB 2.0 for ubuntu and added webcam in the filer.
Ubuntu is detecting my webcam even the webcam light is turning on but, it's showing a black screen in every camera app.

I have **HP wide vision HD** webcam, what to do?

Comment: Does inserting the webcam driver ```uvcvideo``` help you ? Try: ```sudo modprobe uvcvideo```